# Can I add a shortcut to replace a path in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, path

For example, I always go to this path:

> /user/something/somefolders/somewhere

but I don't want to type

> cd
>   /user/something/somefolders/somewhere

in the terminal all the time, can I have some short hand to do so? for example, can I do something like

> cd commandPlace

to replace the path?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use the environment variable `CDPATH` for this. From the Bash man page:

> **CDPATH**
>
> The  search  path  for  the cd command. This  is  a  colon-separated  list   of directories  in  which  the shell looks for destination directories specified by the cd command.  A sample value is ".:~:/usr".

In your case, you can set

```
export CDPATH=.:/user/something/somefolders
```

in `~/.bashrc`, and then typing `cd somewhere` would take you to `/user/something/somefolders/somewhere` (assuming there's no directory named `somewhere` within the current directory).

Alternatively, if you don't want to refer to the folder `somewhere` by its real name, you could create a hidden directory that contains a symbolic link to `/user/something/somefolders/somewhere` with the name you want to use. It could also contain links to any other directories you frequently visit. Then set `CDPATH` to include the path to that hidden directory. Although note that with this method, if you `cd somewhere` and then `cd ..`, you'll wind up in the hidden directory. That may or may not be an issue for you.

Answer (score 63):

Two shortcuts I use all the time for things like this:

**Aliases**

```
alias somedir='cd /home/john/www/something/'
```

Then you can type `somedir` to go to that directory. Add these to your `.bashrc`.

**Symbolic Links**

```
ln -s /long/path/to/some/other/folder /shortcut
```

This will make a file at `/shortcut` which links to `/long/path/to/some/other/folder`. Then you can type cd `/shortcut` instead. The caveat of this is it fills up your root directory (or whichever directory you put the links in) pretty quick. I prefer aliases.

Comment: nice one John !

Comment: it's supposed to be `ln -s /long/path/to/some/other/folder /shortcut` when I did it the other way around it created the shortcut in the place I wanted to create the link to. I submitted an edit to make it updated.

Comment: How about a directory in the root with a short name, e.g. `/sl` and create shortcuts in there? (ie `ln -s /long/path/to/some/other/folder /sl/shortcut`? No clutter in the root, plus a visual reminder that your prompt's path is a symlink.

Answer (score 13):

I tend to use the bash interactive search all the time. Try it. Invoke it with **ctrl+r** and start typing some part of your path, like *somewhere*. Probably your cd command will pop up. :)

Answer (score 11):

Another thing you can do is to store the path in question in an environment variable. Add these lines to your `~/.profile` file:

```
somedir=/user/something/somefolders/somewhere
export somedir
```

You can then access the directory with

```
cd "$somedir"
```

Comment: This is by far the best solution imo because you can use the variable for any command. If you assign an alias then that alias is always tied to a command like cd...

Comment: This is the solution I was hoping existed, and was looking for. For the reasons BdN3504 has stated.

Answer (score 9):

Look at the "alias" command.

In csh:

```
alias commandplace "cd /user/something/somefolders/somewhere"
```

In sh:

```
alias commandplace="cd /user/something/somefolders/somewhere"
```

But I like the symlink solution:

```
ln -s /user/something/somefolders/somewhere ~/commandplace
```

Note: ln takes arguments in the same order as cp.

Answer (score 3):

You can create an `alias` to execute that command:

1. Create a new file `~/.bash_aliases` (if not already created)
2. Add this to that file: `alias something='cd /user/something/somefolders/somewhere'`. Save file.
3. In a new terminal window, type 'something' and it'll `cd` to that path.

It is recommended that all user added aliases should be added to `~/.bash_aliases`.
This file is directly read from `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 1):

The `alias` method described by other answers is the most direct route.

Another option is to try [autojump](http://github.com/joelthelion/autojump), described as "A `cd` command that learns". More description in [this LifeHacker post](http://lifehacker.com/5583546/autojump-is-a-faster-way-to-browse-your-filesystem).

Answer (score 0):

The following is taken from a ***ZSH*** (not bash or sh) book:
[image]

You can use a hash to give a particular directory an alias. This is particularly convenient for your workspace:

```
% echo $GOPATH
  /Users/gfestari/workspace/go
```

I don't want to type `/Users/gfestari/workspace/go` each time I want to reach the src folder in my `$GOPATH` directory. So how about putting hash to a good use?

```
% hash -d gosrc=$HOME/go/src
```

And now we can get there as quick as typing `cd ~gosrc` (pay attention to the leading `~` character).
Here's another example, this time using the `/var/www directory`:

```
% hash -d www=/var/www
% cd ~www
  /var/www
```

You can go ahead and hash your most frequently visited directories. Just remember to add the required entries to your `.zshrc`, so you don't have to type the same thing over and over again.

For bonus points, set the `AUTO_CD` option, so you only need to input the directory's name whenever you want to change the working directories:

```
% setopt autocd
% ~www
  /var/www
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, use an alias.
1- Open the file bashrc which is hidden in the home directory with

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

###### (you can see the bashrc file by typing 'll' into the terminal, it is located at the top with the files which begin with dots.That's where your aliases go.)

2-When nano opens .bashrc you wanna type the alias keyword followed by the name you wanna give to the alias example:

```
alias name_of_your_alias='cd ~/Documents/lectures/lecture1 file'
```

3- This is the last step and also a very important one most people skip this and their aliases do not work, this is the step where you use the source command to sort of update your .bashrc file so the commands are read from it.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

###### (I said source sort of updates the .bashrc file but source doesn't really do that it just makes it so that commands are read and executed from this file.)

4- Enjoy using your aliases.
Happy hacking!!!