# cd shortcuts: symbolic link to CDPATH dir

Tags: macos, command-line, unix, symbolic-link

I found a solution to [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/167221/can-i-add-a-shortcut-to-replace-a-path-in-linux) and posted here and wanted to implement it.

On OSX, in order to create `cd` shortcuts, it advised creating a hidden folder with symbolic links, and then adding that to the `CDPATH` variable. Well, I tried, and I am kind of a UNIX rookie so I'm coming for advice.

Here's what I did:

```
mkdir ~/.shortcuts   
ln -s /mydir/here/ ~/.shortcuts/mydir    
open ~/.bashrc
```

add this line :

```
export CDPATH=.:~/.shortcuts
```

close all Terminal windows and re-open then tried the shortcut `cd mydir`

Can you see what I am missing?

Comment: Can you try replacing the `~` with `/home/user`? I.e. replace the relative path with the absolute path in the definition of `CDPATH`.

Comment: Modified it to `export CDPATH=.:~:/Users/amejia/.shortcuts` and no dice. I'm reading up on `CDPATH` i think my syntax may be off?

Comment: Did it work? If not, add the directory that `cd ~` takes you to to *replace* the `~` in the path. If it did, awesome :-)

Comment: Is this an OSX system by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using OSX, as far as I know `open` is specific to macs, in the Linux world you have `xdg-open`. Please make sure to always mention your exact operating system in your question.

Now, assuming you are indeed using OSX, the file you should edit is `~/.bash_profile` and not `~/.bashrc`. The OSX terminal app starts login shells by default and these do not read `~/.bashrc`. Also, it is generally good practice to always quote variable declarations. So, open `~/.bash_profile` and add this line:

```
export CDPATH=".:~/.shortcuts"
```

Also, you don't need the link, you can simply add the directories you want to the `$CDPATH` varilable:

```
export CDPATH=".:/mydir/here/:/mydir/there/:/mydir/everywhere/"
```

Comment: using `.bash_profle` was the solution. I'll take note of your other advice, and make sure to specify OS. Ty.

Answer (score 0):

Once I found the problem described by @terdon, using an Alias was a much simpler solution.

In .bash_profile:
`alias go-myDir="cd /Volumes/Active/Dir"`

Now, typing `go-myDir` in the Terminal, is a shortcut for the entire cd command

[Improving Terminal workflow with Alias](http://mac.tutsplus.com/tutorials/terminal/speed-up-your-terminal-workflow-with-command-aliases-and-profile/)